# For a pdf $f(x)$, how can we prove that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\,f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x\geq t)\,dt$?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, integration

$f(x)$ is a probability density function and $F(x)$ is the corresponding cumulative distribution function, i.e., we have the relationship on the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$.

Given this, how can we prove the following equation, which can then be used to prove the expectation?
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x\,f(x)\,dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F(x\geq t)\,dt$$

Comment: Are you sure that equation is correct? We have an $x$ on the RHS that is unaccounted for on the LHS.

Comment: I think the equation works only for positive $ x $ and for general RV it is a bit different

Comment: As given, the question is meaningless, since on the RHS there is a $t$ which does not appear on the LHS.

Comment: I am very surprise! You are integrating on $t$ so why should it appear on LHS at all!!

Comment: However I think there is huge problem with the notation of the question. If $F$ is CDF "FUNCTION", then $F(x>t)$ is meaningless. Probably you mean $\Pr(X\geq t)$, with capital $X$ which means the probability that the random variable $X$ is bigger than or equal to $t$.

Comment: Thanks for all your helps. My question is not correct. $F(x \geq t）$should be $Pr(x \geq t)$$, and it seems the integration domain should also be refined to obtain the final conclusion.

Comment: Ok, I see, I mixed it up, my error.

Comment: I suspect you actually want $\displaystyle \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} x\,f(x)\,dx=\int_{t=0}^{\infty} \Pr(X\geq t)\,dt -\int_{t=-\infty}^{0} \Pr(X\leq t)\,dt$ or $\displaystyle \int_{x=-\infty}^{\infty} x\,f(x)\,dx=\int_{t=0}^{\infty} (1-F(t))\,dt -\int_{t=-\infty}^{0} F(t)\,dt$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that $X$ is a positive random variable for the moment. First consider that:
$$
x=\int_0^\infty \mathbb 1_{t\leq x}~~\mathrm dt
$$
Using this equality we can write:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} x\,f(x)\,dx=
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb 1_{t\leq x} \,f(x)\,dt~dx.
$$
Now it is enough to exchange the order of integrals (Fubini's theorem) to get that:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb 1_{t\leq x} \,f(x)\,dt~dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \mathbb 1_{t\leq x} \,f(x)\,dx~dt\\
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{t}^{\infty}  \,f(x)\,dx~dt\\
=\int_{0}^{\infty} \Pr(X>t)\,dt.
$$
Note that $F(t)$ is CDF which means that :
$$
\Pr(X>t)=1-F(t).
$$

Comment: You should note for the beginners that the integral is the expected value of $X$ ;-). Sometimes the equation is useful for finding it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind and patient reply. My question is not absolutely correct.

Comment: @olivia, this is really a nice euphemism. You should be *much more* careful in formulating your questions, so that people which would like to help you don't spend the time on guessing what you really mean.